# Device owner on Android TV Box not working

Tags: java, android, adb, device-owner

I want to install my application as device owner on Android TV Box and I get the next exception.

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner 
"com.android.testapp/.receivers.AdminReceiver"
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't set package com.android.testapp as 
device owner.
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.runSetDeviceOwner(Dpm.java:115)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.onRun(Dpm.java:82)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.main(Dpm.java:38)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:251)
```

There are no accounts on the device. It works on my phones but not on the Android TV Box.

Comment: I think you are trying to execute this command pro-grammatically. If yes, you cannot achieve pro-grammatically.

Comment: @Dhruv I  trying to execute this command in a terminal window

Comment: Having same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: @pa1.Shetty did you find any solution?

Comment: @WaelAbo-Aishah No Haven't found any solution.

Answer (score -1):

Format your Android TV Box.
Enable your developer option in Android TV Box
Connect your Terminal with the IP address with command
adb connect 192.168.X.XX

Install the apk
Run below command to 
adb shell dpm set-device-owner /.DevAdminReceiver

Answer (score -3):

Steps to `set-device-owner` through cmd,

1. Connect your device with USB debugging mode.
2. Set directory using `cd` command to `...Sdk\platform-tools`
3. Write `adb shell` and hit enter
4. You will see `shell@degas3g:/ $` in cmd
5. Now write `dpm set-device-owner com.android.testapp/.receivers.AdminReceiver` and hit enter
6. Your app will become Device Owner.

For more information [Click Here](http://florent-dupont.blogspot.in/2015/01/android-shell-command-dpm-device-policy.html)

**EDITED**

Receiver must be like this.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.Receiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.device_admin"
        android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I'm doing the same thing

Comment: see my updated code. Is your receiver look like this?

Comment: Yes, my receiver looks like this and  It works on my phones but not on the Android MiBox3